# PTIJ: Erasing Amalek's name written on Andy's toys' shoes

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Was Andy from Amalek? Would that explain why Buzz Lightyear and Woody's shoe his name is written on it (since there's an Inyan to write Amalak's name on the bottom of your shoe to erase their memory)?

[image: Buzz Lightyear's shoe]
[image: Woody's shoe]

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 2):

A.N.D.Y

'Annihilate der Yidden'